# create db if not exists in postgres .sh file

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, devops

I want to execute these lines in the below .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh +x
sudo su postgres
psql -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'test_db'" | grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE test_db"
```

But only 'sudo su postgres' is executing and the 2nd line is not executing. Can someone help me execute those 2 lines

Comment: Try `sudo su postgres -c 'psql -U postgres ... '`.

Comment: it is working, thanks @RenaudPacalet

Comment: Can you also say how to take db name as input in .sh file?

Comment: Yes, just unquote/quote and replace the db name by `$1`. The tricky part is the quoting. Do you want to take `pg_database` as a parameter or is it `test_db`?

Comment: i want to take pg_database as parameter. Both the test_db are parameters

Comment: can you help me to take datname = 'test_db' as input

Comment: Simple. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your `psql` command to `su`:

```
sudo su postgres -c "psql -U postgres -tc \"SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'test_db'\" | \
  grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE test_db\""
```

If you want to pass the `datname` value as a parameter, replace it by `$1` in the script (`$1`, `$2`, etc. expand as the first, second, etc. parameters you pass to your script):

```
sudo su postgres -c "psql -U postgres -tc \"SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$1'\" | \
  grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE $1\""
```

and call your script like this:

```
./script.sh test_db
```

You can even have optional parameters. For instance, if you want an optional parameter for the table name (`pg_database` in your example):

```
db=pg_database
if [ -n "$2" ]; then db="$2"; fi
sudo su postgres -c "psql -U postgres -tc \"SELECT 1 FROM $db WHERE datname = '$1'\" | \
  grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE $1\""
```

and call your script like this:

```
./script.sh test_db
```

to use the default, else:

```
./script.sh test_db other_pg_database
```

Comment: I dont want to take pg_database as input parameter.
`sudo su postgres -c 'psql -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$1'" | grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $1"' `
 when i run the above bash file like this: `./script.sh my_db` it is showing error `ERROR: column "my_db" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = my_db ^ ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE`

Comment: "_I dont want to take pg_database as input parameter._": please try to be consistent. In a comment of your question you wrote: "_i want to take pg_database as parameter_".

Comment: The error you got is from your PostgreSQL database server. It tells you that there is no column named `my_db` in table `pg_database`. Can you execute this SQL query by hand? If yes, what is the exact syntax (including the quotes) that works?

Comment: yes you are right it was my mistake but the 1st input parameter (`where datname = '$1'`) when I ran it was decrypted as `where datname = my_db` instead of `where datname = 'my_db'`. I want my_db in single quotes. Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The quoting is quite complicated because we need to first quote the command passed to `su`, then, inside the quoted string, we must quote the SQL query passed to `psql`, and inside this we also must quote the value of the `datname`column. Have a look at the last version of my answer. Use exactly the same double-quotes, single-quotes and backslashes.

Comment: A way to simplify all this would be to avoid the `sudo su postgres` and have your script running the `psql` command directly. Could you, for instance, run your script with `sudo su postgres -c "script.sh my_db"`?

Comment: `sudo su postgres -c 'psql -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = "'""$1""'"" | grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE '$1'"'`
this works thanks Renaud for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your sudo configuration so you can directly express that you only need to as postgres and not root:

`sudo -u postgres ...`

For example:

`user host = (postgres) command`

where user is your user, host is the host name you want this apply (ALL?), and command is the name of your command (ALL?) possible prefixed with "NOPASSWD: " if you don't want to require a password.

Then do the action and deal with the error if needed instead of guarding against it:

`sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $1"`

Possible single quoting the $1 and if you want that to be robust, escape any single quotes in the database name.  I showed you a shell (bash) in the above, so can easily tag on error handling.